# How to enable cookies for Android phonegap 1.8.0 app?

Tags: android, cookies, cordova

I understood that in order to use cookies inside of phonegap native app there must be piece of code which enables it.

When building phonegap for iOS using xcode 4 there is such piece of code inside of phonegap template.

Could you please advice me which code and where I need to put in order to enable cookies for Android phonegap 1.8.0 app?

Please note that I'm using the eclipse Indigo 3.7.2 for building of the app.

Many thanks.

Cheers,
Sinisa.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are trying to use local cookies (file://) you have to make the parent Phonegap project accept local cookies. To do so, You should have a file called youappname.java in your PhoneGap project, probably with this contents or similar:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class App extends DroidGap {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
}
```

Modify it to look like this example:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class App extends DroidGap {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
}
```

Comment: setAcceptFileSchemeCookies is not available on version 10 of android.  Is it on by default there?

Comment: If you want to use this before API lvl 12, try adding `CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);` right underneath `super.loadUrl(...);` instead of the example above. This should work since API lvl 1.

Comment: For API level below 12, CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true); right underneath super.loadUrl(...) is not working. Am I missing anything?

Comment: What about a way to make the cookies available in ajax communications to a web server?

Answer (score 3):

you actually wanna do

```
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      try{
          CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
      }catch(Throwable e){}
```

Since the CookieManager does not exist on older Android versions

Answer (score 0):

If my memories are good, the Phonegape's template loads your start-up web page (ex: index.html) by loading it from the webview (something like :  `super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");`). The latter is declared in the main activity (a ".java" file).

So, first, find the instruction that loads your web application. Then, add the following lines  before the `webview.loadUrl` so that you can obtain something like this :

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

Finally, refresh the Android's project and relunch the app.