# Enable cookies for iOS 7 in PhoneGap Build

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm trying to get my `WebApp` to work on my iPad (iOS 7). According to all the research I've done, it seems like you need to enable cookies specifically (goodness knows why!)

I found this post on SO:

[How to enable cookies for Android phonegap 1.8.0 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083160/how-to-enable-cookies-for-android-phonegap-1-8-0-app)

Thats all good and well, apart from the fact I'm using `PhoneGap Build` to create my app (thus don't have access to those files to edit)

Can anyone suggest what I can do? It seems insane that I can't use `localStorage` (or cookies) on my iOS app without doing this hack! (my app works perfectly on Android, which doesn't have this issue).

I've looked at installing XCode and manually coding/compiling the app, but this will only work on a Mac (which I don't have)

**UPDATE:** Having a look around, it seems that the only solution (I can find), is to write a plugin to enable the cookies. Thats all good and well- but:

- I don't have a Mac to write it on
- I can program a lot of languages, but Java is not one of them
- How would I even get it added to their build list, so I could include it!

Would anyone be interested in writing a plugin for me? As far as I can see it would just need to invoke:

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

This is driving me up the wall!

Comment: Maybe this plugin is useful for you ? https://github.com/bez4pieci/Phonegap-Cookies-Plugin

Comment: Thanks - not sure that does what I need though :) I found a way to get it working, by setting a 1.5 second timer on the initial script load, which then seems to give iOS time to boot up the cookie side of things. Insane, I know... but it works!

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Actually I use cookies a lot in my PhoneGap apps and I don't have problems. Strange...

Comment: Yeah - the weird thing is that it works ok with Android, but just not iOS. It was giving errors like `"document.localStorage is not defined"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just going over my questions, and thought I'd answer this one - It seems that for some reason, iOS doesn't like loading the **localStorage()** on the page ready. To get around this, you have to also set a 1.5 second timer - so it doesn't run before iOS has loaded **localStorage()**. i.e:

```
setTimeout(function() { doInit() } , 1500);
```

This isn't ideal - and it would be much better if there were a way to enable cookies for iOS in `PhoneGap Build`, without having to be able to write a plugin to do it (which I don't have the skills to do ;))

Comment: You seem to have the android code. I don't know where to make the edit in the phonegap source, although in earlier versions of phonegap that was easier. Try including your localStorage function in the device ready callback available in phonegap applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to `document.localStorage` (as commented above) that will be the problem, since `localStorage` is a property of `window`, not of `document`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant window.localStorage :)