# Phonegap/Cordova: stateful request to the server using SESSION

Tags: php, ajax, session, cordova

I have searched a lot but couldn't find an answer to my question.
I am using Phonegap/Cordova which communicates with server Apache/PHP.
After login the app polls the server every minute to see what happened, and uses $_SESSION['userid'] to query the database (so the DB knows the user).
The problem is that for every ajax request the SESSION is not maintained, maybe because since the ajax request comes from file:/// and not from the server, the PHPSESSID is regenerated for every request and doesn't match with PHPSESSID on the server.
It's like I have to authenticate every time.
In other words, SESSION was made to give 'state' to the web, but in my case this 'state' doesn't work.
Do you have any advice??

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that my problem is only related to Android platform, not set to accept cookies. It accepts doing a little easy tweak and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083160/how-to-enable-cookies-for-android-phonegap-1-8-0-app) there is the solution.